# How can I split a matrix whose elements are nested tuples into blocks in Python?

Tags: python, matrix, split

The problem is how to split a matrix into blocks.

If I have a 4x4 matrix looks like this.

```
[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h], [h, i, j, k], [l, m, n, o]]
```

and I want to split into blocks as following:

```
[a, b]  
[c, d]  

[h, i]  
[j, k]

[e, f]  
[g, h]  

[l, m]  
[n, o]
```

But `a`, `b`, `c`...`o` are nested tuples, such as `a = [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...(xn,yn)]`. The `n` is not necessarily equal for each element in the matrix.

Is there any built in function can do that or I have to manipulate the indices and pick the elements one by one? I tried to use `np.vsplit()` and `np.hsplit()`, but they didn't work for my data.

Update:
`np.vsplit()` and `np.hsplit()` will probably solve my problem, but there is one more problem remaining. The data I get are 16 lists of coordinates, but the length of these lists (the number of 2d-coordinates in each list) are not equal. In order to use `np.vsplit()` and `np.hsplit()` I have to convert the 16 lists into numpy ndarray and reshape it. The shape of this ndarray should be something like `(4, 4, x, 2)` which means they are placed in `4` rows, `4` columns, each element has `x=number_of_coordinates_in_that_list`and `2` columns. Can I use `np.reshape()` to achieve what I want?

Comment: What you have shown is a list, not a numpy array. You can just slice them, e.g. ``matrix[0][:2]`` gives ``[a, b] ``. It does not matter what ``a``, ``b``, etc actually are.

Comment: When I tried to use np.vsplit() I did convert the list to a numpy array and reshape the data to the shape that I want. I'm actually trying to write a modified version of pooling function. I did try to use indices to slice them, but I got lost soon because I want to use the kernel size and matrix size as variable.

Comment: So the question you are asking isn't actually your problem?

Comment: My problem still is how to split the list into blocks. I know, just like your reply, that my data is actually a list, but I got lost tracking the indices for elements in each block cause it's a 1D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem eventually and want to summarize it.
My data is something like

```
[ 
    [(1.008,0.177),(1.035,0.511),...,(3.221,0.472)], 
    [(0.332,0.122),(1.023,0.115),...,(3.323,0.427)], 
    ...,
    [(0.212,0.141),(1.023,0.115),...,(3.892,0.918)],
]
```

I don't know how to describe this kind of data in English, but it's essentially a list, whose elements are tuples in list. It's 1D, but I want to use this data as a 2D matrix and split it into blocks like what I've described in the question.

I just find the indices of each block in the 1D list and slice it.

```
Data = [ [(), (), ...], [(), (), ...], ... ]
# Calculate block start index(Upper left).
rows = int(matrix_size / block_size)
columns = int(matrix_size / block_size)
index_0s = []
for row in range(rows):
    for column in range(columns):
        index_0s.append(row * matrix_size * block_size + column * block_size)

def generate_block(block_start_index):
    indices = []
    for i in range(block_size):
        for j in range(block_size):
            index_ij = matrix_size * i + block_start_index + j
            indices.append(index_ij)
    block = []
    for block_index in indices:
        block.append(Data[block_index])
    return block

# Generate all blocks.
blocks = []
for index_0 in index_0s:
    block_i = generate_block(index_0)
    blocks.append(block_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
[[i[:2],i[2:]] for i in a]
```